# C++. Правильное удаление динамического двумерного массива

Tags: c++, массивы, классы, указатели

Всем привет. Я новичок в программировании и только начинаю многое осваивать(хотя и имею кое-какую подготовку, но считать её хоть сколь-либо серьезной смешно). Знакомлюсь с классами, пытаясь соорудить нечто для работы с матрицами. Код реализации не важен, важно то, что получаю ошибку:
http://prntscr.com/e6y5on
Ключевой вопрос в том, как её исправить.

Matrix.h:

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

class Matrix
{
  private:
    int m_rows = 1;
    int m_cols = 1;
    int** m_matrix = new int* [m_rows];

  public:
    Matrix(int rows, int cols);

    void SetSize(int rows, int cols);
    void Create();

    int rows();
    int cols();

    ~Matrix();

};
#endif
```

Matrix.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "matrix.h"

using namespace std;

Matrix::Matrix(int rows, int cols)
{
    SetSize(rows, cols);
    Create();
}

void Matrix::SetSize(int rows, int cols)
{
    m_rows = rows;
    m_cols = cols;
}

void Matrix::Create()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_rows; i++)
        m_matrix[i] = new int[m_cols];

    cout << "Matrix created with " << m_rows << " rows and " << m_cols <<
         " cols." <<         endl;
}


int Matrix::rows()
{
    return m_rows;
}

int Matrix::cols()
{
    return m_cols;
}

Matrix::~Matrix()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_rows; i++)
        delete[] m_matrix[i];

    delete[] m_matrix;
    cout << "Matrix deleted" << endl;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
int main()
{
    Matrix m(2,2);
    return 0;
}
```

При пошаговой проверке в Visual Studio программа сыплется на удалении внешнего указателя delete[] m_matrix; 
Собственно, прошу помочь =)

Comment: Было бы лучше, если бы вы добавили текст ошибки в вопрос не как ссылку

Comment: Буду иметь ввиду. Новичок на stackoverflow)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Давайте разбираться.

```
int m_rows = 1;
int m_cols = 1;
int** m_matrix = new int* [m_rows];
```

Итак, у вас *сразу* выделяется память и создается матрица 1x1.  Поскольку в конструкторе

```
Matrix::Matrix(int rows, int cols)
```

у вас нет инициализации членов, они инициализированы по умолчанию этой матрицей.
Но что вы делаете дальше? Вы переписываете `m_rows` и `m_cols`, и в **уже выделенный массив для ОДНОГО указателя** записываете их `m_rows`, т.е. в данном конкретном случае - два.

Вот вам и источник ваших неприятностей. Ваша попытка исправить ситуацию - это просто попытка не заметить ошибку. Ни к чему хорошему привести это не может. В следующий раз вы запишете туда их с десяток, и таки засорите память основательнее, только и всего.

Вот как по-хорошему должна выглядеть ваша матрица:

```
class Matrix
{
  private:
    int m_rows;
    int m_cols;
    int** m_matrix;

  public:
    Matrix(int rows, int cols);

    void SetSize(int rows, int cols);
    void Create();

    int rows();
    int cols();

    ~Matrix();

};



Matrix::Matrix(int rows, int cols)
:m_rows(rows),m_cols(cols)
{
    m_matrix = new int*[m_rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < m_rows; i++)
        m_matrix[i] = new int[m_cols];

    cout << "Matrix created with " << m_rows << " rows and " << m_cols <<
         " cols." <<         endl;
}

Matrix::~Matrix()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_rows; i++)
        delete[] m_matrix[i];

    delete[] m_matrix;
    cout << "Matrix deleted" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо =)

Comment: @Ari если ответ Вам понравился голосуйте за него (стрелки слева). Это бесплатно.

Answer (score 4):

Судя по всему вы создаёте int** m_matrix размером один, а потом передаёте параметр 2 и думаете что там 2 строки. Видимо вам лучше создавать динамичкский массив в методе Create:

```
void Matrix::Create(){

m_matrix = new int*[m_rows];

for (int i = 0; i < m_rows; i++)
    m_matrix[i] = new int[m_cols];

cout << "Matrix created with " <<m_rows<<" rows and "<<m_cols<<" cols."<<         endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

В классе имеется обращение за пределы выделенной памяти. Если вы добавите следуюшие два предложения в конструктор

```
Matrix::Matrix(int rows, int cols)
{
    std::cout << "m_rows = " << m_rows << std::endl;
    std::cout << "m_cols = " << m_cols << std::endl;

    SetSize(rows, cols);
    Create();
}
```

то при создании объекта класса на консоль будет выдано сообщение

```
m_rows = 1
m_cols = 1
```

Это означает, что перед тем. как тело конструктора получило управление, была выполнена инициализация членов класса

```
int m_rows = 1;
int m_cols = 1;
int** m_matrix = new int* [m_rows];
```

в результате которой была выделена память для массива указателей из одного указателя типа `int *`.

Однако в функции `Create`, так как в общем случае значение m_rows, заданное в конструкторе, может отличаться от 1, то происходит выход за пределы динамически выделенного массива.

```
void Matrix::Create()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_rows; i++)
        m_matrix[i] = new int[m_cols];

    cout << "Matrix created with " << m_rows << " rows and " << m_cols <<
         " cols." <<         endl;
}
```

Нет никакого смысла инициализировать члены класса в определении класса вместо того, чтобы инициализировать их в конструкторе.

Имейте в виду, что вам необходимо также определить конструктор копирования и копирующий оператор присваивания, или определить их как удаленные.

Comment: Премного благодарен =)

Comment: @Ari Не за что. Спрашивайте еще.:)

Answer (score 1):

Вы неправильно выделяете память. Эту строку:

```
int** m_matrix = new int*[m_rows];
```

необходимо перенести из заголовка (`.h`) в реализацию функции `Create()`:

```
void Matrix::Create()
{
    m_matrix = new int*[m_rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < m_rows; i++)
        m_matrix[i] = new int[m_cols];
}
```

В заголовке оставляете только объявление указателя:

```
int** m_matrix;
```

Деструктор возвращаете к вашему первоначальному виду:

```
Matrix::~Matrix()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_rows; i++)
        delete[] m_matrix[i];
    delete[] m_matrix;
}
```

Comment: Грамотная организация классов для меня всё ещё не совсем ясная тема, а потому продолжаю копать. Спасибо)

Answer (score -3):

Нашёл ответ на собственный вопрос. Не знаю дело ли в классе или же это так правильно, но удаления

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_rows; i++)
delete[] m_matrix[i];
```

Оказалось более чем достаточно.

Comment: В этом случае будет утечка памяти

Comment: Нет, категорически неправильно. И утечка - минимальное зло: вы просто замаскировали ошибку (см. мой ответ).

Comment: Уяснил, спасибо.